# Limpar Formularios Navegação Android

Tags: php, android, html

Criei uma aplicação PHP+MySQL e está tudo ok!

Minha dúvida é quando acesso esta aplicação via Tablet, por exemplo, acessando o *login* e senha, após utilizar o sistema, clico em *logout* (*session* *destroy* via PHP) o mesmo direciona para a tela de *login* novamente, porém, mantém salvo o usuário e senha.

Existe alguma forma de eliminar este salvamento automático?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o atributo `autocomplete` do html5, que pode ser definido para todo o formulário, ou apenas para um elemento em especifico.

```
<form action="/login" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    Login: <input type="text" name="usuario"><br>
    Senha: <input type="text" name="senha" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```